# Spark-submit options for gcs-connector to access google storage

Tags: python, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using spark-job on a **self-managed** cluster (like local environment) while accessing buckets on google storage.

```
❯ spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.12.10, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_292
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user centos on 2021-05-24T04:27:48Z
Revision de351e30a90dd988b133b3d00fa6218bfcaba8b8
Url https://github.com/apache/spark
Type --help for more information.
```

If I run the job with the following command using locally download `gcs-connector`, it finishes successfully.

```
spark-submit\
 --name CreateAllDataDFWithSpark\
 --jars ./gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.2.jar\
 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2\
 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem\
 <path_to>/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-TZFypELR-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/luigi/contrib/pyspark_runner.py\
 /tmp/CreateAllDataDFWithSpark78itslb5/CreateAllDataDFWithSpark.pickle
```

On the other hand, If I run the job without downloading `gcs-connector` beforehand as below,

```
spark-submit\
 --name CreateAllDataDFWithSpark\
 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2,com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.2.2\
 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem\
 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS\
 <path_to>/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-TZFypELR-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/luigi/contrib/pyspark_runner.py\
 /tmp/CreateAllDataDFWithSpark1gf54xue/CreateAllDataDFWithSpark.pickle
```

it gives the following error.

```
  ...
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;JJ)V
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.cooplock.CooperativeLockingOptions$Builder.build(CooperativeLockingOptions.java:58)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.cooplock.CooperativeLockingOptions.<clinit>(CooperativeLockingOptions.java:33)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.<clinit>(GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.java:383)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:246)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:58)
    ... 29 more
```

I do not understand why the second command does not work.

I appreciate any suggestions or comments.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this running on Dataproc or a self-managed Spark cluster? In the second command it looks like you're still specifying the GCS connector as a package for Spark to download - what happens if you don't specifying anything about the GCS connector at all? A default Dataproc cluster already has the GCS connector installed so that you don't need to specify configs or download jars.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is on self-managed Spark cluster, for example, a local Google Compute Engine. I am updating the question.

Comment: Seems there is a conflict of Guava version between the GCS connector and Spark (or others), https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md#troubleshooting-the-installation. The 2 ways above will result in different orders in classpath, one of them happened to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this stems from a Guava version incompatibility between the GCS connector's dependency vs what you have bundled in your Spark distro. Specifically, the [GCS connector hadoop3-2.2.2 depends on Guava 30.1-jre](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/gcs-connector/hadoop3-2.2.2) whereas [Spark 3.1.2 brings Guava 14.0.1 as a "provided" dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/3.1.2).

In the two different commands, it was more-or-less luck of the draw that classpath loading happened in the right order for your first approach to work, and it could end up failing unexpectedly again when other jars are added.

Ideally you'll want to host your own jarfile anyways to minimize runtime dependencies on external repositories (Maven repository), so pre-installing the jarfile is the right approach. When you do that, you should consider using the [full shaded jarfile (also available on Maven central)](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/bigdataoss/gcs-connector/hadoop3-2.2.2/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.2-shaded.jar) instead of the minimal GCS connector jarfile to avoid classloading version issues in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will use the full shaded jarfile.

Comment: the full shaded jarfile make it work ! thank you so much

Comment: Facing same issue, while submitting spark job on DataProc cluster, How can include this shaded  connector jar, I tried passing it to spark-submit command in jars option